# Regarding the signs in the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, conventions, representation-theory

Let's take, for example, the $\frac{1}{2}$ $\frac{1}{2}$ spin case. We have, for $J = 1, M = 0$ $$|1,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|-1 / 2,1 / 2\rangle+|1 / 2,-1 / 2\rangle),$$ and, if we follow the standard PDG table for the CG coefficients, we have also that, for $J = 0, M = 0$ $$|0,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1 / 2,-1 / 2\rangle-|-1 / 2,1 / 2\rangle).$$
$\textbf{My question is}$: Couldn't this last state also be written as $$|0,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|-1 / 2,1 / 2\rangle-|1 / 2,-1 / 2\rangle)?$$
Because it makes sense to me that the only requirements are both that the state is normalized, and that $|0,0\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|1,0\rangle.\\
\\
$

$\textbf{In summary}$: are these two tables both correct? (The table on the left is the unedited PDG table.)
[image]

Comment: Search for “phase convention” in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients) about CG coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  There is a sign convention called the Condon-Shortley phase convention.  The coefficient $C_{\ell_1m_1;\ell_2m_2}^{LL}$ with $m_1=\ell_1$ is taken as positive.  The sign of all other coefficients is taken relative to that one.

In your specific case, we have 
\begin{align}
\vert 0,0\rangle = C_{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}^{0,0}
\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle \vert\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle 
+ C_{\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}}^{0,0}\vert\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle
\end{align}
so the coefficient of $\vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ is taken as positive *by convention*.